# How to find a mount point of a samba share mounted by 'gio mount' command?

Tags: mount, samba, fstab

The other day, I have mounted a samba share using this command.

```
gio mount smb://129.254.xx.yy/mygroup
```

Today, I've forgotten this and tried to mount the share with the same command, and got this message.

```
gio: smb://129.254.xx.yy/mygroup/: Location is already mounted
```

Usually, it was mounted on /run/user/1000/gvfs/ but nothing is found there(my user id is 1000).
How can I find this mount location?

Comment: Does `mount | grep 129.254` show anything interesting?

Comment: @munu hi, nothing shows up. strange.. (I had tried grepping mygroup earlier but nothing..)

Comment: I've found this : https://askubuntu.com/a/996950/140413 (starting nautilus again) and did the mount command, and now it shows!