# can't find gio mounted samba share

Tags: mount, samba

I'm using ubuntu-20.04 and I don't know why this `gio mount` command isn't simple working sometimes.
I did 'gio mount smb://129.254.x.y/docu' and entered id and passwd.
`gvfs-mount -l` (though it give me the command is deprecated) shows an entry below.

Mount(0): docu on 129.254.x.y -> smb://129.254.x.y/docu/
Type: GDaemonMount

But I can't find where it is mounted. I used to have in at /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-
share:server=129.254.x.y,share=docu, but I don't see it now. How can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

I found this earlier but post it now.
[How to restart gvfs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996949/how-to-restart-gvfs/996950#996950)

$ sudo killall gvfsd
$ nautilus -q
$ nautilus

Then you will see, for example, /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=129.254.x.y,share\shanrename/ and can link the directory and use it.